# Web test: how to filter matching data from a data source?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-testing

Noob question on web testing: In step 1 of my web test, I load a `Foo` record, which has a value of `Score` equal to 200.

In a datasource `MyDataSource.csv` I have data like so:

```
Group No Value    Description
1        100      Not so good
2        175      OK
3        250      Pretty good
4        300      Excellent
```

Based on the value of the `Score` field, I want to set a context variable `{{groupNo}}` for use in following steps, which is the group with the highest value that is less than or equal to score.  So in our example, the `groupNo` would be 2.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question.  I created an `ExtractionRule`, and read the source data into a static collection.  In the `Extract()` method, I looked up the appropriate value from that collection and wrote the appropriate value to a context parameter.

That's my workaround, though I'm open to accepting a different answer if anyone has a better solution.